# Print only attributes of file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to print only the attributes (size in particular) of a file without showing the filename? `file -b *` is similar to what I want, but . Maybe there is way of combining `ls -hs` and `file -b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat` is what you're looking for:

Print size in bytes for all files:

```
stat --format=%s *
```

Print file name and size in bytes for all files:

```
stat --format=%n:%s *
```